# Rails 4 - change data type of a column from binary to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my model "projectttype"  I have a column "image" created with t.binary :image and I need to change it to data type string.

This would be my first migration and am unsure how to name the migration.

"ChangeImageOnProjecttypes" - does it matter?

And add to the migration file: `change_column :projecttype, :image, :string`

Is this correct or if not, what should it be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the migration doesn't technically matter, but as always, naming is useful to help others understand the code.

Your migration file should contain this:

```
change_column :projecttypes, :image, :string
```

notice the `s` (tables' names are plural)

Answer (score 1):

Your name doesn't big matter, but you can put your migration name as `ChangeTypeBinaryToStringProjecttypes`

and your migration as:

```
change_column :projecttypes, :image, :string, limit: 200, null: true
```

You can refer document as: [document](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column)

Comment: What does limit: 200, null: true do?

Comment: you can set limit length for column image. `null: true` allow image column can be null value. It just options.